# Undefined variable in prototype function

Tags: validation, prototype, javascript-objects, dom-events

I am learning oops in js and was writing simple validate class using prototyping. I don't know why I am getting `undefined variable field` in `validateField` function. But, I can access this variable in `addListener function`.
Can someone explain why variable is undefined and help?
 Below is my code:

```
var Validate = function(formId){
  this.form=formId;
}

Validate.prototype.addValidation=function(field,condition,message){
  this.field=field;
  this.condition=condition;
  this.message=message;
  this.objform=document.getElementById(this.form);
  this.addListener();
}

Validate.prototype.addListener=function(){
  console.log(this.objform);
  document.addEventListener("submit",this.validateField,false);
}

Validate.prototype.validateField= function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(this.field);
}


 $( document ).ready(function() {
    var obj=new Validate('user');
    obj.addValidation('fname','req','Field is Required');
})

 I am able to solve my problem by binding "this" using      
 addEventListener("submit",this.validateField.bind(this),false);
```

but now the problem is when I try to call `addValidation` method a couple of times passing different field names -- e.g. 'fname' and 'lname' -- I get the alert message showing `lname` both the times, thus overriding the `fname` field. I don't understand why this occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you instantiate a new validate with

```
var obj = new Validate('user');
```

this will reference the same object everytime you call obj.addValidation(), with how you are storing your field, condition, message in the addValidate method on the prototype, whatever is called last will be assigned to this.

An easy way to keep your same functionality is to possibly store an object in the addValidate method on this that contains this information.

```
Validate.prototype.addValidation=function(field,condition,message){
  // don't overwrite existing validation rules added
  this.validations = this.validations || {};

  // no need to keep two values of field saved, can use key names if you need to know field names saved
  this.validations[field] = {
    condition: condition,
    message: message
  };

  this.objform=document.getElementById(this.form);
  this.addListener();
}

Validate.prototype.validateField= function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // you would no longer call this.field, but would reference this.validations with either a for in loop,
  // or Object.keys
  Object.keys(this.validations).forEach(function(fieldName) {
    alert(fieldName);
  }
}
```